# Data Transfers to Big Query error "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1"

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, transfer

Hello im currently trying to establish daily data transfers from  Google Cloud Storage to Big Query tables. Theses tables are just meant to store raw data (JSON files) and i unnest them later with scheduled queries. I have no issue when i create the table manually but im getting the error  `Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1` when i launch a test transfer (even if I previously deleted the data in the table).

Here is an example of the raw data table/JSON schema:

```
{
  "fields": [{
    "name": "data",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "schema": {
      "fields": [{
        "name": "relationships",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "schema": {
          "fields": [{
            "name": "createdBy",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "validationWorkflow",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "projects",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "expensesReport",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "agency",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "files",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "resource",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "validations",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "orders",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "data",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "name": "attributes",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "schema": {
          "fields": [{
            "name": "plannedTimes",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "REPEATED"
          }, {
            "name": "state",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }, {
            "name": "exceptionalTimes",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "REPEATED"
          }, {
            "name": "closed",
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }, {
            "name": "informationComments",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }, {
            "name": "regularTimes",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "batch",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "title",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }, {
                "name": "workUnitType",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "activityType",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "reference",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }, {
                "name": "project",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "reference",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }, {
                "name": "row",
                "type": "INTEGER",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }, {
                "name": "delivery",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "endDate",
                    "type": "DATE",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "startDate",
                    "type": "DATE",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "title",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }, {
                "name": "startDate",
                "type": "DATE",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }, {
                "name": "duration",
                "type": "FLOAT",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }, {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "INTEGER",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "updateDate",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }, {
            "name": "creationDate",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }, {
            "name": "absencesTimes",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "schema": {
              "fields": [{
                "name": "workUnitType",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "schema": {
                  "fields": [{
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "activityType",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }, {
                    "name": "reference",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                  }]
                }
              }, {
                "name": "duration",
                "type": "FLOAT",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }, {
                "name": "startDate",
                "type": "DATE",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "name": "term",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "name": "type",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }, {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "date",
    "type": "DATE",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }]
}
```

I know that BQ works better with JSON newline delimited format but this table must contains raw data even if its just 1 row in the end. The weirdest thing is that the transfer works for some files with similar schemas.

What should I do to make these transfers work ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: So you are trying to use Data Transfer Service to load json files from GCS to a table in BigQuery that has this specific schema that you shared, right?

Comment: Yes exactly like a daily routine.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding GCP documentation, I would say that [using JSON newline delimited format is a known limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations).

`"JSON data must be newline delimited. Each JSON object must be on a separate line in the file."`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i found what was the problem. One of the fields was auto detected as  "TIMESTAMP" and there was a format issue in my json that Google Transfers couldn't handle

Comment: Cool! If the issue is solved, would it be possible to post the solution as an answer to make it easier to the community in case someone else is facing the same situation in the future? :) It is important to work together to keep this forum updated and community-friendly. Thank you.

Comment: Done ! (sorry was on vacation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Some of the fields were auto-detected as "TIMESTAMP" when uploading manually. However, Data Transfer didn't recognize these fields as "TIMESTAMP" during the daily updates of these tables.
To solve this I edited the schema and declared these fields as "STRING".

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue while I was working with Cloud DataFlow [ Apache Beam ] to migrate .csv data from Cloud Storage to Google BigQuery.

This error occurs during the conversion of .csv file to .json file resulting into an error. I resolved this issue by adding few lines of code to convert .csv file to .json file.

CSV file:

```
Gender,Math,Physics,Chemistry
male,57,50,53
male,63,66,59
male,65,56,54
```

CSV to JSON conversion:

Your output data must be in this below format then only it will load data to Google Bigquery.

```
[ {"Gender":"male","Math":"57","Physics":"50","Chemistry":"53"},
{"Gender":"male","Math":"63","Physics":"66","Chemistry":"59"},
{"Gender":"male","Math":"65","Physics":"56","Chemistry":"54"}, ]
```

Python code to convert .csv to .json file

```
count = "start"
lst =[]
final = ""
class csv2json(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,csvFile):
        global count
        global header
        global lst,final
        min_dict={}
        lst=[]
        print("**************")
        print(csvFile)
        print(type(csvFile))
        print("**************")
    #Consider first row as a header
    if "start" == count:
        for item in range(len(csvFile)):
            min_dict[csvFile[item]]=""
        count = "end"
        header = csvFile
    #Consider rest are the value for headers.
    else:
        for item in range(len(csvFile)):
            min_dict[header[item]]=csvFile[item]
     #converting dict into list of dict
        lst.append(min_dict)
        
        final = lst 
        print("**************")
        print(final)
        print(type(final))
        print("**************")
        
    return final
```

Hope my solution works for you as well.

For your reference have a glance here:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-a-table